# split string to array PHP comma seperated and equal sign

Tags: php, arrays

I have a request get string URL as follow:

```
/?city=test,test2,test3
```

I would like to convert this to an array in PHP as follows:

```
['city']=test
['city']=test2
['city']=test3
```

is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid you can't: PHP array elements must always have unique keys, so you can't have multiple keys all with the name `city`

Comment: yes can I have the key to be 'city'

Comment: You can have __one__ element with the key `city`, you can't have more than one.... unless your definition of `unique` is different to mine

Comment: `$cities = explode(',', $_GET['city']);`

Comment: your all different! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LQqq3e03EBQ

Comment: @Dagon touché, "I'm not"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = '/?city=test,test2,test3';

$str = str_replace('/?city=', '', $str);

$cities = explode(',',$str);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($cities);
echo '</pre>';
```

Or if you really want to get an array with a key city, and in this one an array with the cities :

```
$str = '/?city=test,test2,test3';

$str = str_replace('/?city=', '', $str);

$my_array['city'] = explode(',',$str);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($my_array['city']);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you want every key to have the index of `city`, you're going to have to make it like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [city] => test
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [city] => test2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [city] => test3
        )

)
```

**SO HOW DO I DO THAT?** (*you might just ask yourself that.*)

Well you do that easily, with the example below.

```
$names = explode(',', str_replace('/?city=', '', $s)); 

$cities = array();
foreach($names as $city) {
  array_push($cities, array('city' => $city));
}
```

That allows you to call it like this:

```
foreach($cities as $city) {
    echo $city['city'];
}
```

[**Example Demo**](https://eval.in/173496)